# can't convert nil into Hash

Tags: sinatra, datamapper

I am using ruby 1.9.2 and sinatra 1.3.2, Datamapper
I get error: "can't convert nil into Hash"

in /new_record i have a form, and when submitting the form (with some blank fields) instead of getting validation messages i get this error!

here post '/new_record' - because I populating this form with some values of previous form

```
post '/new_record' do
        @projects = Project.all
        @date = DateTime.parse(params[:report][:date])
        erb :new_record
      end

      post '/create_record' do
        @user = User.get(current_user.id)
        if @user.records.create(params[:record])
          flash(:notice => "Report created successfully!")
          redirect "/"
    else
      @projects = Project.all
      @date = DateTime.parse(params[:report][:date])
      erb :new_record
    end
```

I can't guess why because similar form works well:

```
  get '/new' do
    #session[:user_id] = nil
    title "Create new account"
    erb :new_user
  end

  post '/create' do
   @user = User.new(params[:user])
   if @user.save
     session[:user_id] = nil
     redirect  "/"
   else
     erb :new_user
   end
  end
```

I think it is something with `@user.records.create(params[:record])` with create method, that it tries to build hash, but why if it can't build a hash just don't throw error that it couldn't save (build) @user.records dependency ?
Is there any way to work around this? Because I would like to build record using relationship.
Thanks in  advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataMapper is not throwing an error that it couldn't save because it detects a problem even before it tries to save the record. (Also notice that, by default, DataMapper doesn't throw exceptions anyway -- you have to enable it.)

`create` takes a hash with the values you want to set as input. So, according to the mesasge you are reporting, apparently a `nil` was passed to it -- and it's complaining that it can't convert a `nil` to a `Hash`.

Try something like this:

```
@user.records.create({:column => params[:record]})
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought things will happen next way:
I added presence validations to fields, and thought that some parameters of has will be set propely, other leave nil, and on saving record I will handle it like follows
if @record.save 
 "do" 
else 
  erb :template
end

and in template I will show validation erros

Comment: You can use validations, but you have to get past this `hash` :P I noticed that you usually don't upvote answers to your questions. It's good practice to upvote good answers (even those you don't choose as the right one), because it encourages people to answer other questions you may ask ;)

Comment: Sorry, my reputation became 17 today I think, so I didn't noticed that I have ability to upvote.
Thanks for help! 
PS. upvoted your answer )